# How to run Netflix movies on Raspberry PIs using Docker container with Python and Selenium headless?

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi, headless, netflix

I have a Raspberry PI and Docker containers in it.

One of the containers (Python + Selenium script) is supposed to access Netflix headless and run a movie.

It works fine in my Windows PC using Chrome (non-headless) or Firefox driver (headless and non-headless).

Then, because it works on Firefox driver headless I decided to go with it and try on the PI. Unfortunately it doesn't work and I get the same message as always(I am screenshooting the screen in headless mode):

Firefox driver image:
[image: Firefox driver image:]

Chrome driver image:
[image: Chrome driver image:]

I've read some possible fixes here and there with the libwidevine.so and so on, no lucy yet!

Anything else that I might have missed here? Somebody else on the same boat?

Thanks a lot!

It works fine in my Windows PC using Chrome (non-headless) or Firefox driver (headless and non-headless).

Then, because it works on Firefox driver headless I decided to go with it and try on the PI. Unfortunately it doesn't work and I get the same message as always

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and the error stacktrace.

Comment: Do the browser versions match? (container vs desktop)  If so, it could be the protections built-in to the content.... (anti-copying stuff)